# PHP cURL request using proxy with different protocols

Tags: php, http, curl, https, proxy

If i have 2 proxies:

`$proxy1 = array('http', 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX','8080')` and `$proxy2 = array('https','YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY','80')`

And I'm requesting:
`$url1="http://somesite-1.net"` and `$url2="https://somesite-2.net"`

Code to init multi curl:

```
foreach ($urls as $url) {
            // threads
            $ch = curl_init($url); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, $_autoreferrer);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, $_follow_loc);  
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, $_max_redirects); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);    
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);                

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $_connection_timeout);                   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $_curl_timeout);  
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,    true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE,        true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY,         $this->conf->getProxyIP().":".$this->conf->getProxyPort());     //PROXY       
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,     $this->conf->getUserAgent());                                   
            if($referrer = $this->conf->getReferrer() !== false){                                                   //REFERRER
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referrer);
            }



            $tasks[$url] = $ch;

            curl_multi_add_handle($cmh, $ch);
        }
```

Do I need to set proxy protocol http or https to send request?
Because when I'm, checking proxy using sockets - I get message that all ok and proxy is working. But when I'm requesting content using cURL - I get content not from all proxies. I think that the problem is with not setted proxy protocol. I think that I need to set some option in cURL, but don't know what exactly.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * get curl_setopt() params
 *
 * @since 2015/03/21 Saturday
 * @return array
 */
private function __optSets(){
    $this->__setCookie();
    // default:GET
    $options = array(
            CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,  
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_PORT => $this->port, 
            CURLOPT_REFERER => $this->reffer,
            CURLOPT_USERAGENT => $this->userAgent,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING =>'',
            CURLOPT_COOKIE =>$this->_cookie,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER =>$this->_requestHeader, 
            CURLOPT_HTTPGET => true, 
            CURLOPT_POST => false,
            CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => $this->_connect_timeout 
    );
    // if:POST
    if(self::HTTP_MEHTOD_POST === $this->method){
        $options[CURLOPT_HTTPGET] = false;
        $options[CURLOPT_POST] = true;
        $options[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS] = $this->_poststr; ////default type:application/x-www-from-urlencoded
    }

    // if:HTTPS
    if ($this->_isHTTPS) { 
        $options [CURLOPT_PORT] = 443; // !Very important
        $options [CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = false;
        $options [CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST] = false;
    }

    // if:enableProxy
    if(true === $this->enableProxy){
        $options [CURLOPT_PROXY] = $this->_proxyIP;
        $options [CURLOPT_PROXYPORT] = $this->_proxyPort;
    }

    return $options;
}
```

Comment: See method __optSets(),line:282

Comment: Oh, thanks. I'll check it. P.S. pretty profile picture